# MySQL select update subquery with where

Tags: mysql

I have table `cps2sql` with fields 'Spanish_SID' and 'Spanish_Word', and table `spanish` with corresponding fields 'SID' and 'word'.

I want to update `cps2sql` setting `cps2sql` Spanish_Word to `spanish` word.

So I have the following update query:

```
update cps2sql
SET c.Spanish_Word=s.word (
SELECT c.word, s.word
FROM cps2sql c, spanish s
WHERE c.Spanish_SID = s.SID)
```

Is there anything wrong/risky with this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `update join`:

```
update cps2sql c
join spanish s 
on c.Spanish_SID = s.SID
set c.Spanish_Word = s.word
```

Comment: Hi,I was told awhile ago that update/join is very slow.  I've used update/inner join and found that extremely slow.  The tables are roughly 200k rows.

Comment: @user3522145 In this scenario, `update join` may be the best to do it, but you have big data, if you found out any other way to do this, please share it to me.

Comment: Works fast and accurate!

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think it only works if the target field (c.Spanish_Word) is empty.

Comment: @user3522145 No matter `c.Spanish_Word` is empty or not, it should work, do you even try it?

Comment: Yes. of the 80,000 records less than 15000 were updated. Pretty sure they were where contents didn't match.  So I should have said where records don't match because either empty or mismatch.  On further thinking though, it may be because there are 80,000 spanish records in cps2sql and 57,000 in spanish.  Have to give it more thought.

Comment: @user3522145 What if try it with only several record, for example, add `where` clause to limit records.

Comment: Hung up now with another query so have to redo tomorrow.

Comment: All look updated even though only said 15k updated.  I think that the reported updates are only where the record needed to be changed.  So if a record already has the matching content, it isn't included in the update count, only records needing the update are counted.  If the record already contains the same content, it isn't counted in the update as it must not have to update it.